# JQuery Refactoring ( separate codes by functionality, improve readability)

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

recently I have been studying way of refactoring Jquery code to handling UI events.

It was hard to find documents which wrote recently.

So, I write my result via this document and hope reviewing my decision from skilled developers such as you.

<purpose of refactoring>

- separate codes by functionality
- improve readability

Jquery source is composed by html elements' event. So I usually saw coding style below

```
$("#nameText").on("input", function () {
 //Some of actions to control html elements, extract data, validation, ajax request, etc,,, 
}
$("#surveyText").on("input", function () {
 //Some of actions to control html elements, extract data, validation, ajax request, etc,,, 
}
 $("#submitBtn").on("click", function (e) {
 //Some of actions to control html elements, extract data, validation, ajax request, etc,,, 
}
```

It's pretty simple and we can read which action is needed and conducted by some elements action.
But that could be verbose and confusing us because there are many roles and we have to check the element's css attributes which related selector.
Some times, css class name or id don't have proper name which not enough explain role of element or in case of, use navigator function like find() or selector by element hierarchy.

```
$("#s_f01").find("li").on("click", function () {
 //Some of actions to control html elements, extract data, validation, ajax request, etc,,, 
}
$(".s_btn01").on("click", function () {
 //Some of actions to control html elements, extract data, validation, ajax request, etc,,, 
}
$("#submitBtn").on("click", function (e) {
 //Some of actions to control html elements, extract data, validation, ajax request, etc,,, 
}
```

And functions for particular element could be spread out by modified history for adding  function or some of modification.

```
//Codes for Survey Form (line 10 - 200)
$("#s_f01").find("li").on("click", function () {
 //Some of actions to control html elements, extract data, validation, ajax request, etc,,, 
}
$(".s_btn01").on("click", function () {
 //Some of actions to control html elements, extract data, validation, ajax request, etc,,, 
}
$("#submitBtn").on("click", function (e) {
 //Some of actions to control html elements, extract data, validation, ajax request, etc,,, 
}

,,,

//added after statistics function for enable Survey form action(line 1200) 
$("#SurveyFormOpenBtn").on("click", sendStatisticInfo_SurveyFormOpened());
```

Answer (score -1):

<Solution>

1. separate functions by Component to make sure functions will be used by which Component

   - each object have Event and Function. Event will have argument which will be passed by Jquery Element and functions will be used by Events.
   - it makes more easily understanding each function's purpose
   - it prevent spread out particular Element's functions.

```
$(function () {

    var categoryListArea = {
        someEvent: function ($jqueryEl) { }, 
        someFunc: function (str, etc) {}
    }

    var survayArea = {
        someEvent: function ($jqueryEl) { }, 
        someFunc: function (str, etc) {}
    }
    
    var HeaderArea = {  }
```

2. extract code by functionality and declare as function and event to number 1's xxxArea Object.

- via Event function name, we can understand what will be conducted by triggered jquery function.
- each xxxArea Object make more easily separate functions by each components.
- each functions will be maintained by each components.

```
//AS-IS
   $("#nameText").on("input", function () {
        console.log('test');
        var inputtedText = $(this).val();
        //1. Dicide display status of Name Lable Element
        if (inputtedText !== '') {
            $('#surveyLable').show();
        } else {
            $('#surveyLable').hide();
        }
        //2. Dicide display status of Name input Element
        if (inputtedText !== '') {
            $('#surveyText').show();
        } else {
            $('#surveyText').hide();
        }

        //3. Prevent input html characotrs
        if (validateHtml(inputtedText)) {
            alert('&<>\"\'\`=/ are not allowed');
            $(this).val(escapeHtml(inputtedText));
        }
    });
//TO-Be
    var survayArea = {
        inputNameTextEvent: function ($el) {
            var inputtedText = $el.val();
            //1. Dicide display status of Name Lable Element
            survayArea.swithDisplayStatus(inputtedText, $('#surveyLable'));
            //2. Dicide display status of Name input Element
            survayArea.swithDisplayStatus(inputtedText, $('#surveyText'));

            //3. Prevent input html characotrs
            // validateHtml and escapeHtml is used commonly so don't include particular object which represents some component
            if (validateHtml(inputtedText)) {
                alert('&<>\"\'\`=/ are not allowed');
                $el.val(escapeHtml(inputtedText));
            }
        },
        swithDisplayStatus: function (str, El) {
            //Decide display status
            if (str !== '') {
                El.show();
            } else {
                El.hide();
            }
        }
    }

  $("#nameText").on("input", function () {
        survayArea.inputNameTextEvent($(this));
    });

function validateHtml(string) {
    let reg = /[&<>"'`=\/]/g
    return reg.test(string);
}

function escapeHtml(string) {
    return String(string).replace(/[&<>"'`=\/]/g, '');
};
```

- hire is my sample code which explain concept.
- if there are more efficient or more practical way, please let me know.

<SAMPLE CODE>
sample.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="sample.js"></script>
    <style>
      ul#category-tabs {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      ul#category-tabs li {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px #ececec solid;
        padding: 10px 18px;
      }
      ul.sub-category-tabs li {
        padding: 2px !important;
      }
      ul.sub-category-tabs li {
        border-bottom: 0px !important;
      }

      ul#category-tabs li a {
        color: #333;
        font-weight: 700;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-size: 12px;
      }

      ul#category-tabs li a i {
        top: 12px;
        right: 18px;
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        padding: 2px;
        color: #ed6663;
      }
      .bodyContainer {
        float: left;
        overflow: auto;
        position: relative;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="headerArea" class="bodyContainer">
      <div class="barCategory" id="barCategory">
        <ul id="category-tabs">
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:void" class="main-category">
              Home<i class="fa fa-minus"></i
            ></a>
            <ul class="sub-category-tabs">
              <li><a href="javascript:void">CompanyInfo</a></li>
              <li><a href="javascript:void">Product</a></li>
              <li><a href="javascript:void">Pricing</a></li>
              <li><a href="javascript:void">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="survayArea" class="bodyContainer">
      <h3>Dummy survey form</h3>

      <div>
        <form action="" id="surveyForm">
          <div id="nameLable">Name:</div>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="nameText"
            value=""
            placeholder="Please input name"
          /><br /><br />

          <div id="surveyLable" style="display: none">Survey:</div>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="surveyText"
            style="display: none"
          /><br /><br />

          <input
            type="button"
            id="submitBtn"
            value="Submit"
            style="display: none"
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**AS-IS**
sample.js

```
$(function () {

    $("#nameText").on("input", function () {
        console.log('test');
        var inputtedText = $(this).val();
        //1. Dicide display status of Name Lable Element
        if (inputtedText !== '') {
            $('#surveyLable').show();
        } else {
            $('#surveyLable').hide();
        }
        //2. Dicide display status of Name input Element
        if (inputtedText !== '') {
            $('#surveyText').show();
        } else {
            $('#surveyText').hide();
        }

        //3. Prevent input html characotrs
        if (validateHtml(inputtedText)) {
            alert('&<>\"\'\`=/ are not allowed');
            $(this).val(escapeHtml(inputtedText));
        }
    });

    $("#surveyText").on("input", function () {
        var inputtedText = $(this).val();
        //1. Dicide display status of Submit Button
        if (inputtedText !== '') {
            $('#submitBtn').show();
        } else {
            $('#submitBtn').hide();
        }

        //2. Prevent input html characotrs
        if (validateHtml(inputtedText)) {
            alert('&<>\"\'\`=/ are not allowed');
            $(this).val(escapeHtml(inputtedText));
        }
    });

    $("#submitBtn").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //1. Submit survey form 
        $("#surveyForm").trigger("submit");
    });

})

function validateHtml(string) {
    let reg = /[&<>"'`=\/]/g
    return reg.test(string);
}

function escapeHtml(string) {
    return String(string).replace(/[&<>"'`=\/]/g, '');
};
```

**TO-BE**
sample.js

```
$(function () {

    var headrAreaEvents = {
        //...
    }

    var survayArea = {
        inputNameTextEvent: function ($el) {
            var inputtedText = $el.val();
            //1. Dicide display status of Name Lable Element
            survayArea.swithDisplayStatus(inputtedText, $('#surveyLable'));
            //2. Dicide display status of Name input Element
            survayArea.swithDisplayStatus(inputtedText, $('#surveyText'));

            //3. Prevent input html characotrs
            survayArea.preventHtmlCharactors(inputtedText, $(this));

        },
        swithDisplayStatus: function (str, $el) {
            //Dicide display status
            if (str !== '') {
                $el.show();
            } else {
                $el.hide();
            }
        },
        inputSurveyTextEvent: function ($el) {
            var inputtedText = $el.val();
            //1. Dicide display status of Submit Button
            survayArea.swithDisplayStatus(inputtedText, $('#submitBtn'));

            //2. Prevent input html characotrs
            survayArea.preventHtmlCharactors(inputtedText, $(this));
        },
        preventHtmlCharactors: function (inputtedText) {
            if (validateHtml(inputtedText, $el)) {
                alert('&<>\"\'\`=/ are not allowed');
                $el.val(escapeHtml(inputtedText));
            }
        },
        submitSurveyFormEvent: function ($el) {
            $("#surveyForm").trigger("submit");
        }
    }

    $("#nameText").on("input", function () {
        survayArea.inputNameTextEvent($(this));
    });

    $("#surveyText").on("input", function () {
        survayArea.inputSurveyTextEvent($(this));
    });

    $("#submitBtn").on("click", function () {
        survayArea.submitSurveyFormEvent($(this));
    });

})

function validateHtml(string) {
    let reg = /[&<>"'`=\/]/g
    return reg.test(string);
}

function escapeHtml(string) {
    return String(string).replace(/[&<>"'`=\/]/g, '');
};
```

**complement**

```
// actually, there aren't need to pass param $(this) to submitSurveyFormEvent method. 

submitSurveyFormEvent: function ($el) {
  $("#surveyForm").trigger("submit");
}


 $("#submitBtn").on("click", function () {
        survayArea.submitSurveyFormEvent($(this));
 });

//So I tried to remove on event's anonymous function and input survayArea.submitSurveyFormEvent() directly.
//But if do that, submit event was executed infinitely (like executed infinite loop)
//if anyone knows why about this, pleas let me know.

 $("#submitBtn").on("click",survayArea.submitSurveyFormEvent());
```